# Deploy an Elixir REST API on AWS

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, elixir

I need to deploy on AWS an Elixir REST API: most of the tutorials that I have found on internet so far includes Elixir with Phoenix and other features, but what I really need is just to deploy a very simple REST API in AWS.
I don't have experience also on AWS, but I guess that I need to set up an ECS cluster to manage an EC2 instance.

Thanks

Comment: The deployment of your API shouldn't really matter on the choice of the web framework: Phonix or not, your app needs to run somewhere. 

A good idea would be to post relevant steps from a tutorial that you are following and describe the problems you're facing.

You've mentioned ECS, and I think you're overcomplicating things - assuming 1 machine can handle your expected traffic, you should be okay with just 1 EC2 instance

Comment: Check out https://fly.io/ or Heroku for deployment if it is just one app. You're probably better of with going with a managed service for your deployment like Fly.io if you're new AWS and EC2.